# DNS entry for remote server with domain belonging to another entity

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I need my business' client PCs to be able to access a server provided by another company (we'll call it `server1.anothercompany.com`). The server is on the far end of a private network connection, but there is no DNS resolution on the other end to allow me to do the connection by name. The current solution is to use host file entries on the PCs, which is not workable for us over time.

I am thinking I can create a primary DNS zone for `server1.anothercompany.com` on my AD DNS server here (`ns.mycompany.com`), and then configure an A record in that primary zone with the private (10.x.x.x) IP address of the remote server. That should allow traffic to get an authoritative response from my DNS server for the `server1.anothercompany.com` system, while not impacting lookups for any other `*.mycompany.com` systems.

Will that work? Will I break something I'm not thinking about if I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that should work.
2. No, it shouldn't break resolution for any other anothercompany.com DNS records.

Comment: I actually asked question #2 incorrectly - what I meant to ask was, will this break resolution for any other *.anothercompany.com addresses?

Comment: No it won't break anything. Your server will only be authoritative for server1.anothercompany.com and nothing else.